# Showing html table in proper format using some css technique?

Tags: html, css

I've a three column table, the first column is a long string without spaces, such as,

ThisIsMyLongVariableNameInTheTableTDWhichIsCreatingTheProblemForMePleaseHelp

This is causing problem, destroying my page layout, is there a way to wrap text which is without spaces? I tried word-break it didn't work, I tried "fixed" layout property for table, that fixed the table size but the text didn't wrap. What is the best way to show such long strings without space in a fixed size element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS 3 rule:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

See it in action [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEbreak-word.html).

This works well in current versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE8+ (didn't try other browsers).